# data access object in python

Tags: python, mysql, database, dto

6 months ago , i was asked to make a database access for our project that has around 30 tables ,( using the Data transfer object  pattern ) . we were using Microsoft's sql server back then. so i had to write a script that automatically generates the DAO's and DTO's.( automatically build classes, name them appropriately according tables , and then write the query inside the functions ) , save it as .py and put it in the right folder --- it's only text processing anyway ---.

now the management decided to change the databases to mysql. and i am wondering , is there any already made DAO generators for mysql in python ?? because i seen something like this in java. this will save me lot of work . 
Please  inform me if anything was unclear

i use python 2.6 , linux fedora (i have windows machine too ).

thanks in advance

Moayyad Yaghi

Comment: in case my question was not clear , my question is: is  there any DAO or DTO generators for mysql in python ?

Comment: Don't comment on your own question.  If you think it wasn't clear, **update** the question to be clear.  No one reads the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for an ORM, then [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and [Storm](https://storm.canonical.com/) are popular choices.

Answer (score 0):

There is something you are looking for Python 3.6+
[szndaogen](https://pypi.org/project/szndaogen/)